# Iterate over a datareader and send email once per unique combination

Tags: c#-4.0, iteration, unique, datareader

I have a datareader which has columns like this among other columns populated via an SP:

```
ColX    ColY   ColZ 
NYC     100    200
NYC     101    200
EWR     100    200
EWR     100    200
```

I'm trying to iterate over this result, and perform an action like sending an email for every duplicate in the combination of ColX, ColY, ColZ; in the above example EWR-100-200

What is the efficient way to accomplish this given that I have no control over the SP that returns this data in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Hashset<string>` to hold keys for the items you've sent emails to. You can create the keys by:

```
string key = ColX.ToString() + ColY.ToString() + ColZ.ToString();
```

So:

```
var keysUsed = new Hashset<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Assuming you got the values from the columns...
    string key = ColX.ToString() + ColY.ToString() + ColZ.ToString();
    if (keysUsed.Add(key))
    {
        // send email
    }
}
```

The point here is that `keysUsed.Add` will return `true` if the item is added to the `Hashset`. If the key already existed, the method would return `false`.